# Bigquery Python API: create table with comments

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm currently creating sharded tables daily using the Python API.

Is there a way to add the comments for the table's columns when creating the table ? I couldn't see it in the doc but it might still be implemented.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the REST API for BigQuery [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource), tables.Insert takes a table resource, and in the `schema.fields[].description` property, you can put in a description.